# ActionScript 3 Reading a text file for equasion, checking input with the answer

Tags: actionscript-3, text-processing

I am making an educational flash game for small children based on maths, and I want to be able to read from a text file with as3, a question to print in a text box, then take input by the user and compare it to an answer also within that file to check that the user has typed the correct answer, if not load another question for the user to answer.

I have done this sort of thing before, in Visual Basic, to make a Text Language Dictionary where words in a file were separated by an '=' I told the program that they were separated by that character, and the program printed the two words into separate text boxes, in line with each other. Such as: "lol = Laughing Out Loud" was one of the lines.

I want to be able to have a text file that reads, example "2x2 = 4" on one line, then the game will be able to print the left side of the sign to the user, then check the user's input with the content on the right side of the sign to see that the answer is correct.

I hope this is not too confusing. I have attempted printing the file into the text box, but am not sure how to make it print just the question, and not the whole file, then check the answer.

I am a beginner in AS3 and flash, and have acknowledged that this may be an over-the-top experiment for my skill level.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be very hard to find a way in when you want to start with the more complicated stuff in Flash. As Jordan suggested, xml is the best way to request the information. Your xml-file would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myList>
    <excercise>
        <question>What is 2 x 2?</question>
        <answer>4</answer>
    </excercise>
</myList>
```

(you can copy & paste this to notepad and save it as .xml)

In flash actionscript you will need a few items to be able to address this xml. I use the following template in a separate actionscript file, named "Main.as":

```
package 
{

    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.xml.*;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Loader;


    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        var myFile:String;
        var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
        var myList:XML;

        public function Main()
        {           
            myFile =  "myList.xml";
            loadXml();
        }
        function loadXml():void
        {
            xmlLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(myFile));          
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlLoaded);
        }
        function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
        {
            myList = new XML(event.target.data);
            myList.ignoreWhite = true;
            //totalNr = myList.excercise.length(); = the amount of excercises in your file
            //var str:string = myList.excercise[0].question;
            //trace (str) would give you the text of the question of the first excercise
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit**
Let's say you create a textbox on your stage and name it **questionTxt**. To add your question to that textbox, you would say:

```
questionTxt.text = myList.excercise[0].question;
```

Below it, create an input textfield where your students can enter the answer. Call it **answerTxt**.

Also create a check button, so they can press it when they have given their answer. Call it **checkBtn**.

You will also need a function to compare their input with the answer in the xml. I will adress it below.

Now you add an eventlistener to the checkBtn like this:

```
checkBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkAnswer)
```

And the function to check the answer (conveniently named **checkAnswer**):

```
function checkAnswer (event:MouseEvent) : void {
    if (answerTxt.text == myList.excercise[0].answer) {
        trace ("correct");
    } else {
        trace ("wrong");
    }
}
```

You treat your xml-data as an array. The first excercise will be found as myList.excercise[0].question and the second would be myList.excercise[1].question etc.

Comment: or use JSON!  JSON is native to flash 10 now.

Comment: Thank you, I have set up the xml file and flash traces the question, but i know not how to make the question node's data appear in a text box

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of xml? It's perfect for what you are trying to do. As for the loading, use the URLLoader and URLRequest classes. You will need a on complete handler to handle the data once loaded. I would Google xml in as3 to get an idea of how to use it. Then look at the Adobe help docks to figure out the loading. Self learning is the best way to learn so I would encourage you to try your best to figure it out on your own but if you have problems ask them here and I or someone else can help you figure out the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
        import flash.net.*;
        import flash.xml.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import org.casalib.util.ArrayUtil;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        var myFile:String;
        var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
        var myList:XML;
        var questionTxt:TextField = new TextField();
        var questionNumber:uint = 0;
        var correctNumber:uint = 0;     
        var correctAnswer:String;
        var randomAnswer:Array;
        const NUM_QUESTIONS:uint = 3;

        public function Main()
        {   
            right = new Sprite();
            addChild(right);

            myFile = "myList.xml";
            loadXml();
        }

        function loadXml():void
        {
            xmlLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(myFile));          
            xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,xmlLoaded);
        }

        public function randomiseArray(answers:XMLList):Array {
            var rArray:Array = new Array();
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < NUM_QUESTIONS; i++) {
             rArray.push(answers[i]);
            }
            return ArrayUtil.randomize(rArray);
        }

        function nextQuest ():void {
            correctAnswer = myList.excercise[questionNumber].answer[0];
            randomAnswer = randomiseArray ( myList.excercise[questionNumber].answer.children() ); 

            questionTxt.type = "dynamic";
            questionTxt.width = 208; 
            questionTxt.height = 32;
            questionTxt.x = 196;
            questionTxt.y = 101;
            addChild(questionTxt);
            questionTxt.text = myList.excercise[questionNumber].question;

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < NUM_QUESTIONS; i++) {
            var answerTxt:TextField  = new TextField(randomAnswer[i]);
            answerTxt.type = "input";
            answerTxt.x = 196;
            answerTxt.y = 301;
            answerTxt.width = 208; 
            answerTxt.height = 32;
            answerTxt.background = true; 
            answerTxt.backgroundColor = 0xFFF00;   
            answerTxt.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkAnswer);
            addChild(answerTxt);        
            }
            }       

        function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
        {
            myList = new XML(event.target.data);
            myList.ignoreWhite = true;
            totalNr = myList.excercise.length(); 
            nextQuest();
            }

        function checkAnswer (e:KeyboardEvent):void 
        {           

         while (right.numChildren) right.removeChildAt(0);

         if(correctAnswer == e.target.getChildAt(e.target.numChildren - 1).text) correctNumber++;

            if (questionNumber == myList.excercise.length()-1) {
                    trace ("wrong");
                    answerTxt.backgroundColor = 0xFF0000;
            }else{

                    trace ("correct");
                   answerTxt.backgroundColor = 0xFFF00;
                   correctNumber++;
                   nextQuest();
                  }  
            }           

        }

}
```

Do not go like that.
Challenge code to the correct answer was administered in answerTxt, and if it is correct that immediately followed the next question.
How to implement that it does not reach.